# How to estimate sampling coverage of a sample from unknown categorical distribution?

Tags: categorical-data, estimation, coverage-probability

Sorry it seems a pretty basic question, but I cannot find any clue in my probability theory and statistics textbooks.

Let $$X\in D$$ be a categorical random variable of unknown distribution P on domain D, where D is an unknown limited domain.

Let (S,C) be a sample of X, where S={x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>} be unique values in the sample, C={c<sub>1</sub>,c<sub>2</sub>,...,c<sub>n</sub>} be frequency of each unique value.

How to estimate the following coverage and weighted coverage?

coverage:
$$v=\frac{|S|}{|D|}$$

weighted coverage:
$$w=\sum_{x\in S} {P(x)}$$

Comment: If by $|S|$ *etc.* you mean cardinality, then the problem is hopeless, because $D$ could be arbitrarily large--even countably infinite--but full of outcomes with such tiny probabilities that you wouldn't detect them.  Consequently all you can say (without stronger assumptions) is that $0\lt v\lt 1.$ The "weighted coverage" question looks tractable because you have information about the *total* probability of the undetected outcomes.

Comment: For |D|, can we at least know its posterior distribution if we have a Poisson prior of |D|-|S|? For w, I feel like it's not simply Dirichlet. Consider extreme cases: (1) |S|=1, c_1=10000 (2) |S|=10000 and frequency of every value is 1. I feel w has to be different between this two extreme cases, right?

Comment: If you assume a prior for $|D|$ you should have enough information to make progress with the coverage problem.  Your example is a good one. You can view $(1)$ as a Binomial outcome and construct a confidence interval for $w.$  In $(2)$ from the absence of any repeat values you can construct a lower confidence limit for $|D|.$  (I'm pretty sure we have addressed that question somewhere here on CV, around 10 years ago.)

Comment: Thank you, do you still remember the keywords so I can search for the old thread?

Comment: If I did I would have searched for you ;-).